# Adobe Flash Player Installation in Ubuntu 18.04; E: Malformed entry

Tags: 18.04

Please let me know how to install Adobe Flash Player on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS from command prompt. I tried enabling Canonical Partners repository using the following command without any success:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/$(lsb_release -sc) partner"
```

Here is the error message:

```
E: Malformed entry 53 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify what "without any success" means exactly. Was there an error when running the command? Where did it fail?

Comment: I included the error message. In this error message, it states that there is something wrong with the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` on line 53. Most likely, your issue was not on line 53 as my sources list file is not the same as yours. Please include the error message when you ask a question in the future. Thanks!

Comment: If you get a "command not found error" when you try to run the `add-apt-repository` command, run this command to fix the error: `sudo apt install software-properties-common` and then proceed with my instructions below.

Answer (score 3):

The command you executed is incorrect.

First, run the following command to remove the malformed entry:

```
sudo sed -i 's/deb.*partner//g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Next, run the following command to add the `partner` repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
```

You can see here that your entry was missing `ubuntu` and a blank space before `$(lsb_release -sc)`

Additionally, you will need to enable the `multiverse` repository. Run the following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
```

---

The following will install all of the flash player plugins for all the different browsers you may use:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install adobe-flash-properties-gtk adobe-flashplugin browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash pepperflashplugin-nonfree
```